# Where can I buy a keg of Strongbow Cider in Virginia (near DC)?

Tags: cider, keg, buying

I am looking for a place where I can buy Strongbow Cider in Northern Virginia, preferably near Washington D.C.  Does anyone know of a distributor?

Comment: while this site's boundaries aren't explicitly defined yet, it's believed that purchasing commercially brewed products is considered off-topic. Weigh in your comments here: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/28/what-should-be-on-our-faq